# My Select Box is not getting Populated Angular4+

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

i am trying to display no. of days in a select box.
this is my component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="days"> Select no. of Days</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="days" id="days" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let method of days" [value]="method.id">{{ method.days }} </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addsubscription',
  templateUrl: './addsubscription.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addsubscription.component.css']
})
export class AddsubscriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  days: [
    { id: 1, days: 30 },
    { id: 2, days: 60 }

  ];

}
```

The console does not return any errors. also, I have registered 
`formsmodule` in the `app.module.ts`
I am pretty new to angular, can anyone help here??

Answer (score 0):

You are using ngModel with the array, you should use a different name instead,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedMethod" id="days" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let method of days" [value]="method.id">{{ method.days }} </option>
</select>
```

and you should assign not declare the type,

```
 days =  [
    { id: 1, days: 30 },
    { id: 2, days: 60 }    
  ];
```

**[`DEMO STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmq3rm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

use `days=` instead of `days:`

```
days= [
    { id: 1, days: 30 },
    { id: 2, days: 60 }
];

<select [(ngModel)]="day" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let method of days" [value]="method.id">{{ method.days }} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a more detailed solution.

First you should use interfaces whenever it's possible. This will prevent you to assign incorrect data to your variables.

Second, you are assigning a value to your variable, so you should use the equal symbol, however, in my example below, I will use the symbol : to set the type of the variable, and later I will use the symbol = to assign its value.

Let's put everything in together:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface Method {
  id: number;
  days: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addsubscription',
  templateUrl: './addsubscription.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addsubscription.component.css']
})
export class AddsubscriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // An array of Method
  days: Method[] = [
    { id: 1, days: 30 },
    { id: 2, days: 60 }
  ];

  mySelection: number;
}
```

The HTML code will be:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="mySelection" id="days" class="form-control" (click)="showData()">
    <option *ngFor="let method of days" [value]="method.id">{{ method.days }} </option>
</select>
```